# What is the complex structure on the boundary torus of a hyperbolic knot complement?

Tags: knot-theory, hyperbolic-geometry, reference-request

Let $K$ be a hyperbolic knot in $\mathbb S^3$.  Restrict the corresponding representation $\pi_1(\mathbb S^3\setminus K)\to\operatorname{PSL}(2,\mathbb C)$ to the fundamental group of the boundary (the peripheral subgroup) to get a map $\pi_1(\partial N_\epsilon K)\to\operatorname{PSL}(2,\mathbb C)$.  Now $\pi_1(\partial N_\epsilon K)$ is just $\mathbb Z\oplus\mathbb Z$, with two generators $m$ (meridian) and $\ell$ (longitude).  The image of $\pi_1(\partial N_\epsilon K)$ is parabolic, and so (up to overall conjugation) is of the form:
$$
am+b\ell\mapsto\left(\begin{matrix}1&a+b\lambda\cr 0&1\end{matrix}\right)
$$
for some complex number $\lambda\in\mathbb C\setminus\mathbb R$.

What is known about this invariant $\lambda(K)$ of hyperbolic knots?  Has anyone defined/studied it?

Comment: Yes, many people have studied this.  I believe it's commonly referred to as the "cusp shape".   I imagine Ian Agol will come along and have something to say, but it's a standard thing to study.  Google "hyperbolic knot cusp shape" and you'll get plenty of relevant papers. 

Comment: I believe it's known that the meridian of the knot is usually (or perhaps always) the shortest curve in the cusp.  

Comment: FWIW I just asked Morwen Thistlethwaite about this, and he told me there are examples where the meridian isn't shortest

Comment: @Jim: Do they appear in one of the reasonably small censi of knots?  If so, it shouldn't take long to find it with a python script.

Comment: @Ryan - According to SnapPy, the knot K5_15 in the census CensusKnots has merdian just a tad longer than the shortest slope.  The shortest slope is a lens space filling.  On the other hand, there appears to be no such examples (where the meridian isn't shortest) for knots up to 16 crossings.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The conformal structure on the cuspidal torus is usually called the "cusp shape."

See Adams, Hildebrand, Weeks [Hyperbolic invariants of knots and links](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2001854) and McReynolds, [Arithmetic cusp shapes are dense](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10711-007-9192-2), for starters.

See also work on "geometric inflexibility" by Neumann and Reid.

Also check out the work of Marc Lackenby and Jessica Purcell.